# Change the value of JComboBox and JTextfield every time the mouse clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

How can I properly change the value of my Swing Controls like JComboBox and JTextfields every time I click the cells of my JTable which is my data? What I want to do if there are more than one record that has the same first letter of the I selected. Will change the value every time I click based on their row position?

**Screenshot**

[image]

When I clicked one of the values in the JTable it shows the current value in the JTextfield and JComboBox but If I click a again it didn't change? Any help?

**SELECT (For retrieving)**

```
private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String searchSection = Section_SearchSection_Textfield.getText();

String searchSECTIONSETTINGS = "SELECT allsections_list.SECTION_ID, allsections_list.SECTION_NAME, allsections_settings.ADVISER_ASSIGNED, allsections_settings.SECTION_POPULIMIT, allsections_settings.ROOM_ASSGN,\n" +
    "allsections_settings.YRLEVEL_ASSGN,allsections_settings.SCHOOL_YEAR,allsections_settings.SESSION_ASSIGNED\n" +
    "FROM allsections_list\n" +
    "RIGHT JOIN allsections_settings\n" +
    "ON allsections_list.SECTION_ID = allsections_settings.SECTION_ID\n" +
    "WHERE SECTION_NAME LIKE ?";

    try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
                PreparedStatement myFirstPs = myConn.prepareStatement(searchSECTIONSETTINGS);)
               {
                    myFirstPs.setString(1, '%'+searchSection+'%' );
                try (ResultSet myFirstRs = myFirstPs.executeQuery();)
                {
                    sectionJTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(myFirstRs));
                    int result = 0;
                    while (myFirstRs.next())
                    {
                        String myName = myFirstRs.getString(2);
                        System.out.println(myName);
                        result++;
                    }
       }//end of try myFirstRs (ResultSet)
       }//end of try myFirstPs (PreparedStatement)
 }
```

**JTable (MouseClicked)**

```
private void sectionJTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
if (evt.getClickCount() == 1) {
        final JTable target = (JTable)evt.getSource();
        final int row = target.getSelectedRow();
        final int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
        // Cast to ur Object type
        Object value = target.getValueAt(row,column);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value);

String selectSections = "SELECT * FROM allsections_list a JOIN allsections_settings b ON b.SECTION_ID = a.SECTION_ID";

      try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect();
                PreparedStatement myPs = myConn.prepareStatement(selectSections);)
        {
            try (ResultSet myRs = myPs.executeQuery())
            {
                int resultCounter = 0;
                while(myRs.next())
                {
                    Section_SectionName_TextField.setText(myRs.getString("SECTION_NAME"));  
                    Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SECTION_POPULIMIT"));
                    Section_Room_Assignment_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("ROOM_ASSGN"));
                    Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox1.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("ADVISER_ASSIGNED"));
                    Section_Session_Settings_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SESSION_ASSIGNED"));
                    Section_Session_Level_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("YRLEVEL_ASSGN"));
                    Section_SchooYear_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SCHOOL_YEAR"));
                    resultCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When I try to add `System.out.print(myRs.getString("SECTION_NAME"));` in my second Result Set it prints out all the values of my `SECTION_NAME` not the current that I selected.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value);` is this line working after your second click?

Comment: @ReşitDönük yes it changed the value whatever cell I clicked. But the JComoBox and Textfields won't. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try print this `myRs.getString("SECTION_NAME")`? Is it returning the correct value?

Comment: @ReşitDönük yes I tried that but it prints all the value of my ID.

Comment: What do you mean "all the value of my ID"?

Comment: @ReşitDönük oops. Sorry. I mean when I try to add that in my `ResultSet` it print all the values of my `SECTION_NAME`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108548/discussion-between-mia-legaspi-and-resit-donuk).

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem:

```
while(myRs.next())
{
    Section_SectionName_TextField.setText(myRs.getString("SECTION_NAME"));  
    Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SECTION_POPULIMIT"));
    Section_Room_Assignment_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("ROOM_ASSGN"));
    Section_Student_Limit_ComboBox1.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("ADVISER_ASSIGNED"));
    Section_Session_Settings_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SESSION_ASSIGNED"));
    Section_Session_Level_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("YRLEVEL_ASSGN"));
    Section_SchooYear_ComboBox.setSelectedItem(myRs.getString("SCHOOL_YEAR"));
    resultCounter++;
}
```

In the above part you are setting all records to the your components in a while statement. So components will show only the last record, in this case "Gold".

But actually there is no need to querying database in `sectionJTableMouseClicked`. You can get all values by `getValueAt` and set to the components.

Comment: I see this is most of the part which I encounter the error. That's why it's returning the last value. I used `sectionJTableMouseClicked` so I can determine which value is selected so I can easily update my records. Thanks :)

Comment: So you must query only with selected id, or just get the data from the JTable.

Comment: Getting the data from the JTable because I think that's the easiest way to update my record. Thanks for responding.